# Looping through range of cells looking for values

Tags: javascript, loops, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a data sheet that contains a information which is then routed to another sheet based on an option selected in a drop down menu. I have created a script that does this by removing the row based on the string selected in the dropdown and copies it to a new sheet when a button is pressed on the data sheet. However, once it meets a string that doesn't equal the string I'm looking for, it stops.

Below is a sample of the code I have so far.

```
function sendUpdates()
{
  var sheetNameToWatch = "Data Report";
  var sheetNameToDelete = "Hidden - Data Report;
  var valueToWatch = "Send to XXX";
  var sheetNameToMoveTheRowTo = "Hidden - New - Data Report";

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); 
  var range = sheet.getRange("O2:O50");
  SpreadsheetApp.setActiveRange(range);

  for (;range.getValue() == valueToWatch;)
  {
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetNameToMoveTheRowTo);
    var targetRange = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1); 
    var deleteSheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetNameToDelete)
    sheet.getRange(range.getRow(), 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).copyTo(targetRange, {contentsOnly: true});
    sheet.deleteRow(range.getRow());
    deleteSheet.deleteRow(range.getRow()); 
  }


}
```

I would like for it to be able to continuing through the range until the end if possible? Any help really appreciated.

Comment: I think I know what you're going for. Could you post a sample doc with the correct structure? I want to make sure my code follows your organization patterns.

Comment: Hi Brian, I can't share a sample doc unfortunately as the data is too sensitive. If you could provide an example anyways that would be great, if not thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

instead of

```
if (range.getValue() == valueToWatch) {}
```

try

```
if( dataRange.getCell(0, i).getValue() == valueToWatch ) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your for loop from:

```
for (;range.getValue() == valueToWatch;)
```

To:

```
var i = 0,
    numberOfRowsInRange = range.getNumRows();

for (i=0;i<numberOfRowsInRange;i+=1)
```

Comment: Thanks Sandy, this is working in terms of looping through the range but it still only gets the value if it is in the first cell. I've updated my code to include the for loop you've suggested. `code for (i=0;i<numberOfRowsInRange; i++){ if (range.getValue() == valueToWatch){ var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetNameToMoveTheRowTo); var targetRange = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1); var deleteSheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetNameToDelete) sheet.getRange(range.getRow(), 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).copyTo(targetRange); deleteSheet.deleteRow(range.getRow());}} `